# Resolving a list of classes that implement generic interface and abstract class with Autofac

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, autofac, abstract

I am trying to resolve strategy pattern using a factory. This factory generates an open generic interface.  It depends on an IEnumerable of that generic interface. I can obtain an IEnumerable of non-generic to work, but with generics i get an empty list.

I can also resolve the class directly, but not the list.

An additional caveat is that we could have potentially unlimited Repositories, so registering them individually would be painful.

I've tried these ways to register with Autofac

```cs
var dataAccess = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(Repositories.IRepository<>));

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
                       .Where(t => IsAssignableToGenericType(t, typeof(Repositories.IRepository<>)) && !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsInterface)
                       .AsImplementedInterfaces();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
                         .Where(t => IsAssignableToGenericType(t, typeof(Repositories.IRepository<>)) && !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsInterface);
```

```cs
public interface IRepository<T> where T : BaseProcessorType
{
    Task Add(T data);
}

public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseProcessorType
{
    public async Task Add(T data)
    {
        // something
    }
}


public class ActivityRepository : BaseRepository<Activity>, IRepository<Activity>
{
    public ActivityRepository() : base()
    {
    }

    public override async Task Add(Activity data)
    {
        // override
    }
}
```

Then I  would like to to resolve

```cs
var lol = something.Resolve<IEnumerable<Repositories.IRepository<BaseProcessorType>>>();
```

But unfortunately this returns an empty list of IRepositories.

Comment: Which type are you trying to resolve ?

Comment: Editted for clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let's forget about `Autofac` and let's try to get the collection with pure C#

```
IEnumerable<IRepository<BaseProcessorType>> l = new IRepository<BaseProcessorType>[] {
                                                       new ActivityRepository() 
                                                };
```

with the code sample the compiler throw an error

> **Error CS0266** - Cannot implicitly convert type`ActivityRepository` to `IRepository<BaseProcessorType>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The main error is that `ActivityRepository` is not convertible to `IRepository<BaseProcessorType>`. In order to allow this cast you have to make the `T` argument covariant by using the `out` keyword

```
public interface IRepository<out T> where T : BaseProcessorType 
{}
```

But by doing so you can't have a method with a `T` parameter

> **Error   CS1961**    Invalid variance: The type parameter `T` must be contravariantly valid on `IRepository<T>.Add(T)`. `T` is covariant.

To understand why it is forbidden let's see this code sample :

```
IRepository<BaseProcessorType> r = new Activity1Repository();
r.Add(new Activity2());
```

In this code sample `r` works with `Activity1` but you want to add an `Activity2` and `Activity1` is not `Activity2`.

One solution would be not to use `T` as a type parameter but use `BaseProcessorType`

```
public interface IRepository<out T> where T : BaseProcessorType
{
    Task Add(BaseProcessorType data);
}
```

This way the pure C# solution is valid.

In order to resolve a `IEnumerable<IRepository<BaseProcessorType>>` you need to register your types as `IRepository<BaseProcessorType>`.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
       .As(typeof(IRepository<BaseProcessorType>));
```

Comment: Thanks Cyril! I'll accept the answer once i give it a shot :)

Comment: Cyril I do have a question though. If I replace T with BaseProcessorType, is there a point to have T at all?  One of the things i was trying to accomplish, is all types the implement IRepository have a specific type that utilize, that way you can't potentially call ActivityRepository with anything other than an Activity. I mean, I could just do "if typeof(data) != Activity" in there, but that isn't as clean.

Comment: Why do you need an `IEnumerable<IRepository<BaseProcessorType>>` ? there is maybe other options depending on that